# Is it correct to say "too ... of [multiple things]", and are there any alternatives for this saying?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I have heard of the expression "too ... of a(n) ..." many times before (e.g. "too expensive of a price"), but I don't remember this saying being used on a plural noun.

Would it be correct to say (for example) "too expensive of prices"? On the other hand, are there any other expressions for this saying?

In addition, could anyone explain the relevant grammar behind this saying, "too ... of [something]"?

Comment: The only word I can think of that fits comfortably into your sample sentence is "much", for instance "That's too much of a task". However 'much' is quite a general word and only used with only used with uncountable quantities (eg "How much water is there in the tank?").

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are a couple of issues to sort out here.

First, as another answer suggests, the particular example is distracting, because it describes a price as expensive where it would be better to say that the price is high and the item is expensive.

Second, the "too long of a wait" construction is, in my opinion, bad style. The "of" in the middle seems to imitate constructions like "the first of a series" or "the best of a bad lot," where the "of" makes sense. When someone says "too long of a wait," he means "too long a wait," a wait that is too long. If he's uncomfortable with the stilted quality of "too long a wait," he could recast as "a wait that is too long."

(In the examples I'm approving, A of B involves a noun B and "of B" serves as an adjective modifying A. In the examples I'm disapproving, A is an adjective modifying B.)

Third, you seemingly meant to ask whether we could use this construction with a plural noun at the end: "too long of waits."  I guess that you want to say this where you had to wait for the doctor on each of three visits, and each wait was too long. I agree: "He requires too long of waits" is a very weird way to express that. I don't think that it's grammatical either, but I'm not sure what purpose there would be in a gramatical analysis of an expression that obviously defies understanding.

On the other hand, if we trade in the "of" (after the adjective) for a dash (before the adjective), we get a phrasing that seems familiar, as where you make a too-long drive through too-narrow streets to attend a too-loud party with too-boring people. It has a jocular quality, but at least it's understandable whether the noun at the end of each example is singluar (like drive and party) or plural (like streets and people).

Answer (score 0):

"Too expensive a price" is barely acceptable and "too expensive of a price" is downright incorrect. Here is the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+expensive+a+price%2Ctoo+expensive+of+a+price&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) for the research "too expensive a price,too expensive of a price" in Google Books.

[image]

Much less correct is "too expensive prices". However, it is much better to say "too high a price", because "expensive" means "costing a lot of money".

[image]

Comment: “Too expensive a price” is not acceptable in my book. But it’s because it should either be “too ***high*** a price” or just “it’s too expensive”  I.e. prices are not expensive- items are.

Comment: @Jim You are probably right, I do not consider it as good English myself, but you do find it in such texts as [this one](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/ERDA_Authorization_1976_and_transition_p/KTdIRNyp6NMC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22too+expensive+a+price%22&pg=PA486&printsec=frontcover); people use it, as the ngram shows. However, I'll change that. Would you say "hardly acceptable"?

Comment: @lph I’d say “barely acceptable.”